# Can't get files with ExternalStorageDirectory

Tags: android, file, listview, android-sdcard

I found that when I use code below it works on AVD, but when I open it on physical device or Bluestacks - the list is empty, even though that music files are on sdcard. Anyone knows what is going on?

And, if You know how to make it read files from internal memory I would be grateful, cause as I found out - many phones have big memory capacity and they don't use sd cards (some of them even can't).

Here's the code:

```
static Uri[] mUris;
static String[] mFiles = null;
public static String[] getMusic(){

    File music = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // File asd = Environment.

    // String[] savedFiles = getApplicationContext().fileList();

    File[] musicList = music.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return ((name.endsWith(".mp3")||(name.endsWith(".wav"))));
        }
    });

    mFiles = new String[musicList.length];
    for(int i=0; i<musicList.length;i++) {
        mFiles[i]=musicList[i].getAbsolutePath();
    }

    return mFiles;
}
```

Comment: listFiles is not recursive. it lists the content of a directory, but not the content of subdirectory. Are you sure you have files inside /sdcard that ends with mp3 or wav?

Comment: it's in subdirectory. I didn't know that it read only main folder w/out subdirectories. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would suggest you to first find the free space available in sd card
>   read this doc may help you
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html

Comment: I don't know for what should I use finding out free space available.

@Stacks28: Well, some devices don't have sd cards, so I need this one as well.

Comment: thats what i m saying 1. find if sd card available 2. if u want to place in sd card then i m suggesting to check the space available

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I don't need to place anything - just read mp3 files. Did I understand You correctly?

Comment: Nope :/ Still can't read anything. I'm struggling with reading the documentation because it list the methods, but don't show how to really use them (or at least I don't know - in their training there is so much more examples). Maybe that's the issue - my incapability to read documentation?

Comment: Alright let me know via mail when u r available will chat in stackoverflow and will solve the issue